# Problem with OpenSSL when starting rail server after upgrade Homebrew

Tags: ruby, openssl, homebrew

I have an old Ruby React project that works fine. When I revisit again after months and start the rail server, I got the error as below.

I am trying a bunch of different solutions, but nothing works so I am totally lost.
I suspected this happened because I might upgrade my homebrew and it does not support SSL 1.0.0 anymore and the SSL old version (1.1.0) might be deleted as well.

MY SSL INFO:

```
ls -al /usr/local/Cellar/openssl*
total 0
drwxr-xr-x   3 resant  staff   96 Oct  5 20:32 .
drwxrwxr-x  11 resant  admin  352 Oct  5 20:29 ..
drwxr-xr-x  14 resant  staff  448 Oct  5 20:32 1.1.1g
```

ERROR:

```
1: from /Users/resant/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
/Users/resant/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require':
dlopen(/Users/resant/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/x86_64-darwin17/digest/md5.bundle,9): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib (LoadError)
Referenced from:
Users/resant/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/x86_64-darwin17/digest/md5.bundle
Reason: image not found -
Users/resant/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/x86_64-darwin17/digest/md5.bundle
```

I try this solution:

```
brew update && brew upgrade
brew uninstall openssl
brew install https://github.com/tebelorg/Tump/releases/download/v1.0.0/openssl.rb
```

but when I run that brew install, I got the following error:

> fatal: 'origin' does not appear to be a git repository fatal: Could
> not read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository
> exists. fatal: Needed a single revision invalid upstream
> 'origin/master' Error: Calling Non-checksummed download of openssl
> formula file from an arbitrary URL is disabled! Use 'brew extract' or
> 'brew create' and 'brew tap-new' to create a formula file in a tap on
> GitHub instead. If reporting this issue please do so at (not
> Homebrew/brew or Homebrew/core):
> https://github.com/tebelorg/Tump/issues/new

I don't understand this at all so I might be screw up things even more. Please help, how should I fix this?

Comment: Instead of downgrading to openssl1.0, which may break packages that depend on openssl1.1, I'd first try to re-install Ruby 2.5.1 to link it against openssl1.1.

Comment: I did that, but I might miss something when I tried to link it to the new SSL 1.1. Not sure what.

Comment: Assuming you're using ruby-build, try this command to ensure it links against the right package: `RUBY_CONFIGURE_OPTS="--with-openssl-dir=$(brew --prefix openssl@1.1)" rbenv install 2.5.1`